# I am stuck at TypeError in tkinter. How to fix it? Please guide me

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a python reader project and wanted to make a python reader (In which the python will read what you wrote in the entry) it works fine but when I write something in the entry it gives me a type error:

[image]

and my code:

[image]

The problem is somewhere after clicking a read button before that it works just like I want but after clicking the button the problem happens.

Comment: Please, read how to write a proper question on SO and edit your post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please paste the code here

Comment: You are shadowing functions in the your code. Ex: ```str``` is an inbuilt function but you have used it as a variable in the function, ```speak``` is a function but now it is assigned to some variable

Comment: Please copy the text of your code, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68269153/edit) your question and paste and format it there.

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `funcation` is defined to be given `str` in line 18

```
def funcation(str):
```

but you're calling the function without any arguments from `reader_btn` in line 38: `funcation`

what you want to do is passing the `text` variable containing the string like

```
command=lambda: funcation(text)
```

from your `reader_btn`

EDIT:

or probably better read the value of your entry when the button is pressed:

```
command=lambda: funcation(text_place.get())
```

thanks to quamrana for pointing that out

Comment: It should be ```command=lambda: funcation(text)```

Comment: btw, just executing `funcation(text)` won't work, since `text` is likely to be the context of the text box before the user has had a chance to type anything into it.

Comment: completed @Sujay

Comment: @quamrana, you are correct. But, it is hard unless OP pastes the code here

Comment: @Sujay: Yes, we both await the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my code